# x86 Assembly: How do I get the quotient and remainder from a function

Tags: assembly, x86, return

Here are my questions,

1. How do I store the remainder from edx back at the memory address of the third parameter?
2. Do I need to use a subroutine in order to do so?
3. What is the most efficient way to do so?

If you could show the correct code for this or a detailed explanation of how to that would be great. If you could show a combination of the two that would be excellent.

Here is my .asm file:

```
.386

.model flat

public _Divide

.code

_Divide proc

        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
        cwd
        idiv ebx
        mov ecx, [ebp + 16]
        cmp ecx, 0
        jne remainder
        jmp done
remainder:
        mov [ebp + 16], edx   ;this is showing as the minimum value for a 
                              ;long in the cpp(-860,000,000)
done:
        pop ebp
        ret
_Divide endp

        end
```

Here is the .cpp file from which I am calling the _Division function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" long Divide (long, long, long *);

void main ()
{
long    Result;
long    Remainder;
long    Dividend;
long    Divisor;

do
    {
    cout << "Enter Dividend" << endl; 
    cin >> Dividend;
    cout << "Enter Divisor" << endl;
    cin >> Divisor;

    Result = Divide (Dividend, Divisor, &Remainder);
    cout << "Result is " << Result << " and Remainder is " << Remainder << endl;
    } while ((Result >= 0) || (Remainder != 0));

Result = Divide (Dividend, Divisor, 0);
cout << "Result is " << Result << " and Remainder is not used" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're storing the remainder at `[ebp + 16]`, not at the address contained in `[ebp + 16]`. You've got the address in `ecx`, just store it there - `mov [ecx], edx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assembler code has some bugs:

- It clobbers **EBX** which is a saved register (i.e. should retain content across function calls) in the [x86 ABI](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/architectures-and-abis-detailed/).
- You should be using `cdq` (double to quad word) to sign extend **EAX** into **EDX:EAX** instead of `cwd` (word to double word) to sign extend **AX** into **DX:AX**.
- For the `Remainder` out parameter, you were not storing to the location it pointed to.

This code should work:

**div.asm**

```
.386
.model flat

.code
public _Divide
_Divide proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
    cdq
    idiv ebx
    mov ecx, [ebp + 16]
    cmp ecx, 0
    je return
    mov [ecx], edx
return:
    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret
_Divide endp
    end
```

and if we take Jester's suggestion to use a memory operand with `idiv` to reduce our register use, the code becomes:

```
_Divide:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    cdq
    idiv DWORD [ebp + 12]
    mov ecx, [ebp + 16]
    cmp ecx, 0
    je return
    mov [ecx], edx
return:
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: @Sparky10: Also, `idiv` can take a memory operand, so no need to load the divisor into a register; but if you do, you can use `ecx` so `ebx` doesn't need to be saved.

Comment: excellent advice @scottt, jester and frank.  Thank you all for the clarification I truly appreciate it.

Comment: [`test ecx,ecx` is slightly more efficient than `cmp ecx,0`, and sets flags exactly the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  And BTW, instead of saving/restoring `ebx`, you could have just loaded the divisor into `ecx` before reusing `ecx` for the pointer.